# Error initializing C++ map

Tags: c++

I have created the following class:

```
class A{
 public:
 static std::map<std::pair<unsigned, unsigned>, unsigned> var1;
};

std::map<std::pair<unsigned, unsigned>, unsigned> A::var1[std::make_pair(0,0)]=0; //it is used to initialize static variable var1 inside A.
```

However, when I do so I get the following error:

```
array bound is not an integer constant before ‘]’ token
```

Is there some way by which I may initialize var1 with some default values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
static std::map<std::pair<unsigned, unsigned>, unsigned> CreatVar1() {
  std::map<std::pair<unsigned, unsigned>, unsigned> var;
  var[std::make_pair(0,0)]=0;
  return var;
}
std::map<std::pair<unsigned, unsigned>, unsigned> A::var1 = CreateVar1();
```

Or, alternatively, in C++11:

```
std::map<std::pair<unsigned, unsigned>, unsigned> A::var1 = {{{0, 0}, 0}};
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't declare your variable and initialize one of its item using `A[...]=` at the same time.

```
std::map<std::pair<unsigned, unsigned>, unsigned> A;
A::var1[std::make_pair(0,0)]=0;
```

should work. If C++11 you can use bracket initialization as

```
std::map<std::pair<unsigned, unsigned>, unsigned> A = {{{0,0}, 0}};
```

Answer (score 2):

With C++11

```
#include <map>
using namespace std;

map<int, char> m = {{{1, 1}, 2}, {{2, 2}, 3}, ...};
```

Or use boost.assign.

Answer (score 0):

In C++98,you can use a function to inialize your static variable. For example, you can do something like this

```
typedef std::map<std::pair<unsigned, unsigned>, unsigned> mymap;
mymap init() {
 mymap m;
 m[std::make_pair(0,0)] = 0;
 return m;
}

class A {
 public:
  static mymap var1;
};
mymap A::var1 = init();
```

If you can use C++11, it is shorter

```
std::map<std::pair<unsigned, unsigned>, unsigned> A::var1 = {std::make_pair(std::make_pair(0, 0), 0)};
```